# R specifying unit for diff of timestamps

Tags: r, datetime, difference

How do I specify the units I want to use when doing a diff of POSIXct values?

For example,

```
times <- c("2015-04-20T07:45:00Z","2015-04-20T07:30:00Z","2015-04-20T07:45:00Z","2015-04-20T07:45:00Z","2015-04-20T08:00:00Z")
time <- as.POSIXct(times,format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
diff(time)
```

Produces

```
Time differences in secs
[1] -900  900    0  900
```

Any idea how I could specify this time in minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `difftime`

```
 difftime(time[-1], time[-length(time)], unit='min')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
?difftime

time1 - time2

difftime(time1, time2, tz,
         units = c("auto", "secs", "mins", "hours",
                   "days", "weeks"))
```

Comment: It also shows, what other options he can try in `difftime`